# SQL Automatically Delete one of two duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query which finds duplicate IDs

```
 SELECT uniqueID2, count(uniqueID2) as 'count'
                                  FROM gpDetailAfterMultiplier
                                   group by uniqueID2
                                  having count(uniqueID2) > 1
```

this produces an output something like:

```
uniqueID2     count
111111111       2
111111112       2
111111113       2
111111114       2
```

How do I automatically delete one of the two duplicates?

I can do this one at a time by doing

`DELETE top(1) from gpDetailAfterMultiplier where UniqueID2 = '111111111'`

is there any way to do this so that it automatially 'loops' through each result and deletes one of the two duplicates for each unique id?

Comment: Do you have another column that is really unique - like an `id`?

Comment: @juergend no unfortunetly not :/ this is why I need to get rid of the duplicates

Comment: Do you have any other columns at all in this table?

Comment: @shree.pat18 yes but the rows are exact copies

Comment: Also, are there only 2 records for each ID or are more possible?

Comment: Add a primary key that is autonumber, that will give you something that is unique.

Comment: The "unique" column doesn't even need to be universally unique; just unique between the records with the same id. That way you can join on `uniqueID2` and `Max(some_other_column)` and only get one record. Something like an insert date

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT *,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY uniqueID2 ORDER BY uniqueID2)
   FROM gpDetailAfterMultiplier
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

It will delete all duplicates from the table.

See result in [**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/febe0/1) (Used `SELECT` query in fiddle to see which records are going to be deleted).

Comment: Care to adapt your example to the OP's question?

Comment: thanks for your reply, will this only delete one of the two duplicates or both?

Comment: @neeko: It will delete all others except one (See the result in fiddle).

Comment: @neeko This answer works so I have deleted mine.

Comment: Why did I get a downvote for the right answer?

Comment: Updated fiddle to show results of delete. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/a8e93/1